# What is the difference between these two different dictionary constructions?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'm trying to create the variable `mfc_table_count` using a dictionary comprehension. I've created the dictionary using for loops as so:

```
mfc_table_count = {}
for tag in word_counts:
    for word in word_counts[tag]:
        if word not in mfc_table or word_counts[tag][word] > mfc_table_count[word]:  # initialise word key or replace word key with higher count
            mfc_table_count[word] = word_counts[tag][word]
```

Then I created the dictionary comprehension based on the above:

```
mfc_table_count = {}
mfc_table_count = {word:(word_counts[tag][word]
                          if word not in mfc_table_count
                          or word_counts[tag][word] > mfc_table_count[word] 
                          else mfc_table_count[word]) 
                    for tag in word_counts for word in word_counts[tag]}
```

However, these two dictionaries don't produce the same result (they do produce similar results though).

Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong here?

Thanks so much.

Comment: what are the results you're getting?

Comment: Among other things, the for-loop version says `if word not in mfc_table`; the comprehension version says `if word not in mfc_table_count` (which is `{}`, since the re-assignment of the comprehension result hasn't happened yet). But more importantly, to translate accurately, you should leave *all* of the `for` *and* `if` clauses in the same order. See https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/ for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translation from the loop version to a comprehension is mechanical: put the *innermost* thing in front (modified appropriately - for a list comprehension we just take the argument to `.append`, and for a dict we isolate the appropriate key and value from the assignment), and then all of the `for` and `if` clauses, in the *original* order.

https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color covers how this works for list comprehensions in detail; dict comprehensions are analogous.

We also skip the initial `mfc_table_count = {}`, since it doesn't help with the comprehension - it will be ignored and replaced (as long as we don't erroneously reference it!).

So:

```
mfc_table_count = {} # redundant
for tag in word_counts: # 1
    for word in word_counts[tag]: # 2
        if word not in mfc_table or word_counts[tag][word] > mfc_table_count[word]: # 3
            mfc_table_count[word] = word_counts[tag][word] # 0
```

becomes

```
mfc_table_count = {
    word: word_counts[tag][word] # 0
    for tag in word_counts # 1
    for word in word_counts[tag] # 2
    if word not in mfc_table or word_counts[tag][word] > mfc_table_count[word] # 3
}
```